# html5 link loads current page: syntax problem?

Tags: html

Problem is in this block, I think:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head/>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Finger Style Guitar Club</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/king/cs50_web/cs50_01/cs50wp0/Assets/css/stylesp0.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Users/king/cs50_web/cs50_01/cs50wp0/Assets/images/favicon_nylon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<head/>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Finger Style Guitar Club</h1>
    <h2>Drop That Pick!</h2>
    <p class="header_p">It's <span><i>gonna</i></span> happen anyway...&#128526;</p>
    <div class="header_d">
      <nav>
        <div >
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
          <a href="#about_me">About</a>
          <a href="#blues_in_a_chart">Chart</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

first two links change to hand on hover,3rd and 4th do not.
copied first two and pasted to no avail.
if "index" is after # in first link, I get file not found.
not sure what to do here...any help?

Comment: That first `<head>` doesn't need a /, and the second needs to be like `</head>`. 

Apart from that, those links look fine if you want to navigate to those anchor IDs on the same page. Maybe the problem lies in your CSS file.

Comment: The problem is you have some invisible characters in your HTML. I retyped the HTML of the third link and it worked fine.

Comment: Your code is not valid html... including what @ravb79 specified. Fixing those tags first will help narrow it down.